# What can I do to help my canvas animation run faster in safari like it does in chrome?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, safari, cross-browser

I've got an animation that runs great the first few times on safari. But after each time the loop is triggered it slows down slightly. On chrome I don't experience the slow down. Is there some trick I'm needing to utilize for safari?

External link: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/bgreater/full/vYxoZyj)

Here is my JS example:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let scratch = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctxS = scratch.getContext('2d', { alpha: false });
let vw = window.innerWidth;
let vh = window.innerHeight;
let circleRadius = 50;
let circleSpacing = 3;
let stepDistanceX;
let stepDistanceY;
let originCircle;
let clickNum = 0;
let circles = [];

// Transition vars.
let frame;
let isZooming = false;
let destination;
let dx;
let dy;
let ds;
let dt = 0;
let zoomingImage;

// For matrix circles.
function setCircleSizes() {
  if (vw < 600) {
    circleRadius = 20;
    circleSpacing = 2.5;
  }
  else if (vw < 900) {
    circleRadius = 40;
    circleSpacing = 3;
  }
}

// Easing funciton for animation (linear)
function easing(t) {
  return t
}

// On window resize.
function resize() {
  canvas.width = vw;
  canvas.height = vh;
  scratch.width = Math.max(vw, vh);
  scratch.height = Math.max(vw, vh);
}

// Set matrix for circles.
function setCircleMatrix() {
  stepDistanceX = (circleRadius * circleSpacing) + ((vw % (circleRadius * circleSpacing)) / 2);
  stepDistanceY = (circleRadius * circleSpacing) + ((vh % (circleRadius * circleSpacing)) / 2);
  const circlesAcross = Math.floor(vw / stepDistanceX);
  const circlesDown = Math.floor(vh / stepDistanceY);
  let circlesToAdd = circlesAcross * circlesDown;
  circles = new Array(circlesToAdd);
  while (circlesToAdd) {
    const i = circles.length - circlesToAdd;
    const column = ((i + 1) + circlesAcross) % circlesAcross || circlesAcross;
    const row = Math.floor(i / circlesAcross) + 1;
    circles[i] = {
      x: ((vw - (stepDistanceX * (circlesAcross - 1))) / 2) + (stepDistanceX * (column - 1)),
      y: ((vh - (stepDistanceY * (circlesDown - 1))) / 2) + (stepDistanceY * (row - 1)),
      drawn: false
    };
    circlesToAdd--;
  }
}

// Gets the closest circle.
function getClosestCircle(x, y) {
  return circles[circles.map((circle, i) => {
    return {dist: Math.abs(circle.x - x) + Math.abs(circle.y - y), index: i };
  }).sort((a, b) => {
    return a.dist - b.dist;
  })[0].index]
}

// Gets the closest circles by range.
function getClosestCircles(x, y, range) {
  return circles.filter(circle => {
    return Math.abs(circle.x - x) + Math.abs(circle.y - y) < range;
  })
}

// Handle click event.
function getPosition(event){
  if (event.srcElement.tagName === "A" || isZooming) {
    return true;
  }
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left; // x == the location of the click in the document - the location (relative to the left) of the canvas in the document
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top; // y == the location of the click in the document - the location (relative to the top) of the canvas in the document

  if (clickNum < 1) {
    // First click.
    originCircle = getClosestCircle(x,y);
    drawStuff([originCircle], x, y);
  }
  else {
    // Add from origin.
    drawStuff(getClosestCircles(originCircle.x, originCircle.y, Math.max(clickNum * stepDistanceX, clickNum * stepDistanceY)), x, y);
  }

  clickNum++;

}

// This is the zoom animation.
function zoomReset() {
  // break loop if no canvas.
  if (!canvas) {
    return true;
  }

  frame = requestAnimationFrame(zoomReset);

  // Loop it.
  if (dt < 1 && isZooming) {
    dt += 0.08; //determines speed
    // Do alot of stuff in the scratch pad.
    ctxS.clearRect(0, 0, scratch.width, scratch.height);
    const tx = easing(dt) * dx - (((scratch.width - canvas.width) / 2) * (1 - dt));
    const ty = easing(dt) * dy - (((scratch.height - canvas.height) / 2) * (1 - dt));
    const ts = 1 - ds * (easing(dt) * 1);

    // set elements by tx
    ctxS.putImageData(zoomingImage, (scratch.width - canvas.width) / 2, (scratch.height - canvas.height) / 2);
    ctxS.beginPath();
    ctxS.arc(scratch.width / 2, scratch.height / 2, Math.max(scratch.width / 2, scratch.height / 2), 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctxS.clip();
    ctxS.fillStyle = `rgba(255, 79, 23, ${(1 * dt) - (0.2 / (1 * (dt * 2)))})`;
    ctxS.fillRect(0, 0, scratch.width, scratch.height);

    // Update on main canvas.
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, vw, vh);
    ctx.drawImage(scratch, Math.floor(tx), Math.floor(ty), Math.floor(scratch.width * ts), Math.floor(scratch.height * ts));
  }
  else if (isZooming) {
    isZooming = false;
    drawStuff([getClosestCircle(...destination)]);
  }

}

// Draw stuff on the canvas.
function drawStuff(stuffToDraw = [], x, y) {
  // Do circles.
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, vw, vh);
  stuffToDraw.forEach(circle => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF4F17";
    ctx.beginPath(); //Start path
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circleRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Draw a point using the arc function of the canvas with a point structure.
    ctx.fill(); // Close the path and fill.
    circle.drawn = true;
  });

  // Do our zoom.
  if (!circles.filter(circle => !circle.drawn).length && isZooming === false) {
    originCircle = getClosestCircle(x,y);
    const {x:nx, y:ny} = originCircle;
    destination = [nx,ny];
    ds = Math.min(1 - (circleRadius / vw), 1 - (circleRadius / vh));
    dx = nx - ((scratch.width * (1 - ds)) / 2);
    dy = ny - ((scratch.height * (1 - ds)) / 2);
    zoomingImage = zoomingImage ? zoomingImage : ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    clickNum = 1;
    dt = 0;
    circles.forEach(circle => {
      circle.drawn = false;
    });
    isZooming = true;
  }
}

// Start.
canvas.addEventListener("click", getPosition);
resize();
setCircleSizes();
setCircleMatrix();
frame = requestAnimationFrame(zoomReset);
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
```

**UPDATE**: I've found that if I reset the scratch element after using the loop `scratch = document.createElement('canvas'); resize(); ctxS = scratch.getContext('2d', { alpha: false });`, the animation works as fast each time like the first time. Any ideas as to why that is the case?